Alpha vantage - Fetching TSX/TO fails
I am trying to fetch data from canadian exchanges using alpha vantage. However, I constantly receive an error. I have tried with several suffix but without any luck.
Error:
Checking XIU.TO...
Error fetching data for XIU.TO: Unknown error
No data available for XIU.TO

Checking ABX.TO...
Error fetching data for ABX.TO: Unknown error
No data available for ABX.TO

Checking BMO.TRT...
Error fetching data for BMO.TRT: Unknown error
No data available for BMO.TRT

Checking RY.TRT...
Error fetching data for RY.TRT: Unknown error
No data available for RY.TRT

def fetch_data(symbol):
    url = f'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=GLOBAL_QUOTE&symbol={symbol}&apikey={API_KEY}'
    r = requests.get(url)
    data = r.json()

    if "Global Quote" not in data or not data["Global Quote"]:
        print(f"Error fetching data for {symbol}: {data.get('Note', 'Unknown error')}")
        return None

    return pd.DataFrame([data["Global Quote"]])


# List of Canadian stocks with their TSX symbols
canadian_stocks = [
    "XIU.TO",  # iShares S&P/TSX 60 Index ETF
    "ABX.TO",  # Barrick Gold
    "BMO.TRT",  # Bank of Montreal
    "RY.TRT",  # Royal Bank of Canada

Could it be that these instruments are premium or? Also I have tried for both daily and intraday. Ideally I would like intraday.
